# Generate random with uniform distribution in some range

Tags: random, distribution, uniform, q

how can I generate random number with uniform distribution in some range i.e [a, b] using q?

I have found some solution, but truly speaking I don't know how to rewrite it, because those solution generate random numbers in range (0:1].

```
uniformRandomVariate : { []
        (1 ? 1f)[0]
    }
```

Comment: Your `gaussianRandomVariate` code is completely unrelated to the question you've asked, and should be removed - it's a distraction.

Answer (score 1):

Q has a `random` function documented [here](http://q-lang.sourceforge.net/qcalc/qdoc_10.html#SEC67).  Follow the instructions to get a uniform in the range [0,1], call it `u`.  Then `(b-a)*u + a` is uniform over the range [a,b].

Comment: Hi, thank you for help, I have another question. In documentation which you send me there is written: _"...there is a parameterless function random which returns a 32 bit pseudo random integer in the range 0..2^32-1. To obtain a random 32 bit floating point value in the range [0,1], you simply divide random by 0xffffffff."_

So implementation should look like:

`random[] % 0xffffffff;`

unfortunately my interpreter says that function random does not exist...

Comment: Not a q programmer, but have you tried `random % 0xffffffff` without the square brackets?  Looking at the docs I see lots of examples of functions being invoked without brackets.

Comment: Yes, I just  try learn it and yes I have tried without brackets and i still have the same error. I cant use also `seed` function, but other functions works perfect.

Comment: Can't help you then, since it's allegedly a builtin function.  Is there a q guru on-site that you can ask?

Comment: Just found an [example that may help you](http://q-lang.sourceforge.net/qcalc/qdoc_2.html).  Search for "random" about 2/3 of the way down the page.

Comment: I have still the same error with `random` function, but I pick my function `uniformRandomVariate` and then I implement your solution, seems that it works ^^